# ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"demographic_detail", :id=>nil}

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to programming and sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm writing a test for controllers in Ruby on Rails. The test is expecting a parameter but I'm not sure how to do that. When I run the test with rspec  I get the error you see in the title.

This is PART of the controller's code:

```
class DemographicDetailController < ApplicationController

  #before_filter :authorize
  include ::Demographic

  def show

  @cinema_id = params[:cinema_id]
  @cinema = Cinema.find(@cinema_id) 
  @cinema_name = @cinema.name
  @cinmea_address = @cinema.address.full_street_address 
  @cinema_authority_id = @cinema.address.post_code.local_authority_id
  @c_working_age = Population.where(:local_authority_id =>  @cinema_authority_id , :year => Population.maximum("year")).first
  @c_working_age = @c_working_age.working_age_16_to_64

  @c_total_population = totalpopulation(@cinema_authority_id)
  @c_average_income = latestaverageincome(@cinema_authority_id)


  @all_cinemas = Cinema.all

  (...)

  end
```

and this is the test I wrote for show method:

```
describe "Demographic" do
  context "when testing the DemographicDetail controller" do
      #let(:params) { { disabled: false } }
      let(:cinema_id) { create(:cinema) }

it "should show demoraphic details successfully" do

  get :show, params: { id: @cinema_id }  
  assert_response :success

     end

end
```

This is the route:

```
   controller :demographic_detail do
    get '/demographic_detail/show/:cinema_id' => :show
  end
```

Comment: your test  should be ```get :show, id: @cinema_id```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

modify the route as

```
get '/demographic_detail/show' => 'demographic_detail#show'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
get '/demographic_details/:cinema_id' => 'demographic_detail#show'
```

or

```
controller :demographic_detail do
    get '/demographic_detail/:cinema_id' => :show
end
```